# Effective use of idle cores when using parallelization

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

Assume I have 10 cores in a CPU. And I run ParallelMap on them:

```
LaunchKernels[10];
ParallelMap[F1,L1];
```

where `L1` is a list of the dimension `{10,1}` and `F1` is whatever function. Thus, all 10 cores start working hard computing `F1`, each core computes `F1` for a pointed element in `L1`. The issue is that each of the cores finish its work in their own time, and when some are being idle with finished tasks, the others continue computing.

Now, assume, I have to compute several sequent ParallelMaps commands:

```
LaunchKernels[10];
ParallelMap[F1,L1];
ParallelMap[F2,L2];
...
```

With such the order of commands, Mathematica implements the lines step by step and cannot run the second `ParallelMap` until all elements in the first become computed. *(Please, see UPD below)*

Are there ways to load the idle cores with the second task, not waiting for the ending of the first one? I can assign 5 cores for “task 1” and 5 for “task 2”,  but I am sure there are more efficient and elegant ways.

P.S. I am pretty new in Mathematica, and might not know the propper nomenclature and key words. Please, refer me to the topics I duplicate or comment here.

**UPD** After @Domen 's [response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/300132/92499) below, I have to specify the condition:
I would like to have access to the output of the finished calculations made with ParallelMap[F1,L1], while ParallelMap[F1,L1] is still being run.

Answer (score 4):

You can join all your "jobs" into one list, then call `ParallelMap` once.

```
joinJobs[specs__] := Catenate@Table[{s[[1]], #} & /@ s[[2]], {s, {specs}}]

L1 = Array[a, 2];
L2 = Array[b, 4];
L3 = Array[c, 3];

jobs = joinJobs[{F1, L1}, {F2, L2}, {F3, L3}]
(* {{F1, a[1]}, {F1, a[2]}, {F2, b[1]}, {F2, b[2]}, {F2, b[3]}, 
    {F2, b[4]}, {F3, c[1]}, {F3, c[2]}, {F3, c[3]}} *)

ParallelMap[#[[1]][#[[2]]] &, jobs]
(* {F1[a[1]], F1[a[2]], F2[b[1]], F2[b[2]], F2[b[3]], F2[b[4]], F3[c[1]],
    F3[c[2]], F3[c[3]]} *)
```

Comment: **Your response helped me to specify the issue** I concerned of: I would like to load the CPU's and keep tasks distinguished to get the output timely when calculations of each task is finished. What you propose should definitely work, thank you ! However, I would like to have access to the output of the finished calculations made with `ParallelMap[F1,L1]`, while `ParallelMap[F2,L2]` is still being run. Sounds insignificant, but my `ParalellMap`’s takes about a few weeks each, and I prefer to work with intermediate results, not waiting for the end of the full computations. Thank you !

Comment: Why don't you write the results to a file?

Comment: 1) Correct me, you suggested gathering all the functions in a pool and apply `ParallelMap` to them. Whether we can interrupt `ParallelMap` and withdraw an intermediate result ?  If you have a solution I will appreciate it if you share it. I do utilize `Save[...]` after each `ParallelMap`.
2) I am working with a cluster of 8 nodes (PC's) with 20 cores per node. I am not sure, one can safely address the nodes memory while they are in the work process.
3) I do believe one can do it simpler. There has to be a Mathematica command to run the next command if a core is idle after the previous.

Comment: In fact, the approach you suggested, might be described as following:
`Parallelize` of the stack `{ParallelMap[F1,L1],ParallelMap[F2,L2]}`.
I did not manage to handle with the syntaxis # $@ yet, pardon.

It is likely, I will need `ParallelSubmit`, it sounds close to what I think of. But it is not clear how to handle it.